# Pymysql library does not return pure data in database

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x, pymysql

I'm new to Python and especially *pymysql* library.

I want to make query from my database and when query is done , the result is not pure record that is in the database and have some parentheses and "," mark and so on.

This is my code.

I will be thankful if you answer me

```
from pymysql import *
def database_connector():
db = connect(host="localhost",port=3306,user="root",passwd="", 
db='telegrambot',charset='utf8')
return db
def question_return(tests_id,questions_id):
db=database_connector()
cursor=db.cursor()
cursor.execute("""SELECT question FROM questions WHERE test_id = '%s' AND 
question_id = '%s';""",(tests_id,questions_id))
return_value = cursor.fetchall()
return return_value

print (question_return(1,1))
```

and it print some thing like this.

```
(('What is your name ?',),)
```

and I want to just print something like this without parentheses and other marks

```
What is your name ?
```

Please help me how to do this

Thanks a lot

Comment: Because `fetchall()` returns a tuple of tuples.

Comment: so what kind of function and module should i use to return pure data in database

Comment: It *is* returning the pure data. And you don't need any "function or module".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it returns tuple of tuples, You have to iterate over that. Find the below code.

```
from pymysql import *
def database_connector():
    db = connect(host="localhost",port=3306,user="root",passwd="", 
    db='telegrambot',charset='utf8')
    return db
def question_return(tests_id,questions_id):
    db=database_connector()
    cursor=db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""SELECT question FROM questions WHERE test_id = '%s' AND 
    question_id = '%s';""",(tests_id,questions_id))
    return_value = cursor.fetchall()
    return return_value

for r in question_return(1,1):
    print r[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a cursor class into your database connector declaration

```
from pymysql import *

def database_connector():
    db = connect(
        host="localhost",
        port=3306,
        user="root",
        passwd="", 
        db='telegrambot',
        charset='utf8'
        cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor # <-- declare cursor class
    )
return db

def question_return(tests_id,questions_id):
    try:
        with database_connector() as cursor
            query = "SELECT question FROM questions WHERE test_id = '%s' AND question_id = '%s';"
            cursor.execute(query, (tests_id,questions_id))
            return cursor
    finally:
        database_connector().close()

with question_return(1,1) as pointer:
    for row in pointer.fetchall():
        print(row['question'])
```